# Constructors in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller

I've been having a lot of problems recently trying to get my constructor work with my angular project so I created a test component. The code is supposed to toggle a message that says "hello test" by clicking a button. Please let me know why my constructor isn't responding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.component.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="postEvent" 
        ng-controller="postCtrl">
        <button> reg button test </button>
        <button ng-click="toggle()"> toggle test </button>
        <button ng-show="state"> state test </button>
    </div>
</body>

// app.component.js
var postEvent = angular.module("postEvent", []);
postEvent.controller("postCtrl", function($scope) {        
        $scope.toggle = function () {
        $scope.state = !$scope.state; 
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the markup where you set the `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives?

Comment: `<div
      ng-app="postEvent"
      ng-controller="postCtrl">

<button ng-click="toggle()">test </button>
<div ng-show="state" >
    hello test
</div>
</div>`

Comment: You mentioned that you created a test component, but everything you have shown seems to indicate this is not a component, but a full (albeit small) AngularJS app. And you say this isn't working when you try it locally, but the snippet that Sajeetharan provided does work. I'm so confused...

Comment: A created a new angular app to see if the problem in my project. The problem is that I see his code works within the stackoverflow browser but when I try to run it in my project, there is no response within the scope of the script

Comment: If that is the case then there must be some error occurring for you locally. You'll have to use your browser's developer tools to check the console and network. Something is not being loaded, but since we can't see your local environment there's no way for us to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @Lex would it still be considered a browser issue if it works for neither safari or chrome

Comment: I don't think it's a browser issue at all. Most likely it's not loading `app.component.js` because you have not referenced it correctly in your script tag's src attribute.

Comment: I tested this by putting my script in my html directly previously and I still do not get a response

Comment: Ik I’m confused as you are

Comment: Clearly something is different or there's a typo or a missing character...something. If you put everything in a single index.html and then post the contents of that exact file - copy and paste it, don't retype it into the SO editor - then maybe we can spot the issue. Aside from that I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: So u want to see what I see when I copy and paste sajeetharans code?

Comment: When you copy and paste that and then view it locally, are there any errors at all in the console? Does the network tab show any issues at all accessing the CDN for angular?

Comment: [![Its a blank page with no console errors][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SVXj.png

Comment: Yeah, looks like you are trying to run an Angular app - that's not AngularJS. And you're trying to load an AngularJS app inside an Angular app component. Not only that, but you have everything inside an unclosed `<head>` tag. I'm not surprised it's not working. You need to first decide if you are going to use AngularJS (Angular 1.x) or Angular and then follow some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
function ctrl($scope) {    
}
```

which is unecessary here.

DEMO

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="postEvent" ng-controller="postCtrl"> <button ng-click="toggle()">test </button> <div ng-show="state" > hello test </div> </div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var postEvent = angular.module("postEvent", []);
    postEvent.controller("postCtrl", function($scope) {        
            $scope.toggle = function () {
            $scope.state = !$scope.state; 
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now my issue is that the javascript code works in this stackoverflow browser but does not repond when I put it in my angular js project.

Comment: Also the network tab if angularjs reference is loaded properly

Comment: It shows no errors in the console and everything in the network tab has been loaded properly.

Comment: im sure you are missing something very basic

Comment: That’s what I am afraid of. I created a separate html component for this code itself and copied ur code into it and for some reason my JavaScript won’t load

Comment: try to have one html and one js file . refer the js in the html. all should be good

Comment: I still get the same result my html: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="postEvent" ng-controller="postCtrl"> <button ng-click="toggle()">test </button> <div ng-show="state" > hello test </div> </div> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app.component.js"></script>`

Comment: My js is the same script you posted

Comment: try just src="app.component.js"

Comment: Anything I put within the scope of ng-app and ng-controller gets no response

Comment: @Jonathan Can you update your original question so that it contains all the changes you have made in the course of this discussion?